Building arrays in command line and calling them in a for loop as a single command
I am trying to build two arrays (arr1 and arr2 which will have the same length) in the command line to be referenced in a for loop.
Building the command like this from the script,
set arr1[0]="a" & set arr1[1]="b" & set arr1[2]="c" & set arr1[3]="d" & set arr2[0]="e" & set arr2[1]="f" & set arr2[2]="g" & set arr2[3]="h" & for /L %G in (1,1,3) do echo %arr1[%G]% %arr2[%G]%
But this is not considering arr1 and arr2 as arrays but rather considering them as strings?
The output of the above command is as such

What am I missing? I have tried some of these variations but none seems to work for me:

... & for /L %G in (1,1,3) do echo %%arr1[%G]%% %%arr2[%G]%%
Using && as the separator of each command

I am sure its something very simple I am missing but can't seem to get my head around it.
NOTE: I do need all the commands to be as a single string for this command to be useful to me

...  do call echo %arr1[%G]% %arr2[%G]% (see delayed expansion trap)

You clearly are not typing those set commands into a cmd.exe window, obviously already knowing the variable names, values, and quantity of each, just to display them back to you. So when you say "all the commands to be as a single string for this command to be useful to me", there must be some important context that you are omitting. The problem with omitting the real task information is that you are completely ruling out any possibility that the task can be performed more efficiently using a modification. Please do us the courtesy of explaining the real task, so that we have that opportunity.

@Stephan 's comment did help me, that was indeed the missing piece. I can accept it as the answer. The Context is that I am building this command via a script and executing it in the script. The script I am using knows the paths of a bunch of files I need to process and hence I am building this long string which will create an array with all these files, run a loop and run the required command I need. But that requirement was not too relevant to this query (as if I can make this work, I believe I can make the rest of it work as well), hence I did not include it along with the original query.

Do post it as the answer and I can accept it

echo %arr1[%G]% %arr2[%G]% is interpreted as (empty) variable echo %arr1[%, a string G[, another (empty) variable % %, the string arr2[, and a third (also empty) variable %G]%.
The fact that empty variables don't show an empty string on the commandline (other than in a script) leads to an output that looks exactly like a repetition of the thing to be echoed (which I guess is the fact that confused you).
Ok, now that we know, what happens and why - how to solve it?
Well, you need another layer of variable expansion (the first one to expand %G, the second one to expand the variables built with %G (arr1[1] etc).
The easiest way to achieve another layer of parsing is the call command:
...  do call echo %arr1[%G]% %arr2[%G]% 

You can get a rough idea of what's going on here
If you're into deep rabbit holes, get a big pot of coffee and read this (Be warned - it's heavy stuff. Prepare for brain meltdown)
for "nice, undisturbed" output, suppress command repetition (after troubleshooting. Without @ you can actually watch the two stages of variable expansion):
@(set arr1[0]="a" & set arr1[1]="b" & set arr1[2]="c" & set arr1[3]="d" & set arr2[0]="e" & set arr2[1]="f" & set arr2[2]="g" & set arr2[3]="h" & for /L %G in (1,1,3) do @call echo %arr1[%G]% %arr2[%G]%)

